# Can not find module after installing it

Tags: haskell, import

I am trying to install "threepenny-gui", I simply do it by

```
cabal install threepenny-gui
```

It is a school project that I have to use it and you can find the start code [here](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/year/2017/course/TDA555_Introduktion_Till_Funktionell_Programmering/Code/Lab4/Calculator.zip).

After I have installed it and run Calculator.hs without changing anything I get the error

```
ThreepennyPages.hs:13:18:
    Could not find module ‘Data.Aeson’
    Perhaps you meant Data.Version (from base-4.8.2.0)
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

ThreepennyPictures.hs:17:18:
    Could not find module ‘Graphics.UI.Threepenny’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

ThreepennyPictures.hs:18:8:
    Could not find module ‘Graphics.UI.Threepenny.Core’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I read [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Cabal-Install) in section 4.1 that

> This happens when you install a package globally, and the previous packages were installed locally.

But does not give any real solution. How should I install it correctly? Have been having similar problems when installing other modules.

Comment: Are you familiar with the tool `stack`, try to build with it it should take care of this issue

Comment: I have not, new to haskell. But I have been looking for something similar for haskell as virtualenv for python. Ty!

Comment: @Salviati try to use `stack` follow this guide https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/ to setup a new project with haskells "virtualenv"

Comment: How exactly do you "run Calculator.hs"? What command do you type?

Comment: Also, site rules ask that you include any relevant code *in the question itself* (and not at an offsite resource that could potentially go dead before SO itself does). Luckily in your case a minimal reproducing example should be as short as a single file with the contents `import Graphics.UI.Threepenny`, so this should be no burden for you -- but just to make sure, you should test that it is so and edit your question appropriately once you have found a minimal reproducing example.

Comment: this is completely awkward for new comers...  1 day spent to install a package